# Craft 2 Commerce 1 cart session expiry

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft2, session, cookies, timeout

Is it possible to change the cookie timeout just for the cart?  E.g. I'd like to clear abandoned carts after X hours and keep all the other sessions untouched (e.g. user sessions etc).

Please advise anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `commerce.php` config file in your `config` folder and set the `cartCookieDuration` to a time interval. The default is 3 months.

```
<?php
return [
    'cartCookieDuration' => 'P3M',
    'purgeInactiveCarts' => true,
    'purgeInactiveCartsDuration' => 'P3M',
];
```

Comment: Oh that's very helpful!  Thank you!